# Is there a way to build model objects on the background thread in AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm building an iOS application and I was wondering if there is a way to build my model objects from my request results on the background thread. It appears the success callbacks/blocks on AFHTTPClient request methods are all done on the main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dispatch_async`:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        // Do model serialization here, e.g.: 
        // NSMutableSet *mutableRecords = [NSMutableSet set];
        // for (NSDictionary *attributes in [JSON valueForKey:@"records"]) {
        //  [mutableRecords addObject:[[YourModelClass alloc] initWithDictionary:attributes]];
        // }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            // Execute callback passing, e.g.:
            // block(mutableRecords);
        });
    });
```

This would be in the success block of the request operation. The `block` variable would be the parameter passed into the method that made the request. See the iOS example project for more information. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

AFHTTPRequestOperation also has a 'successCallbackQueue' property that by default is set to the main queue, but you can tweak that to be any queue you want.